# Determine height and width of front page in latex

Tags: paper-size

Can I tell my latex-document only to give my first page a specific height and width? 
I tried to use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\setlength\paperheight{296.8cm}
 \setlength\paperwidth{247.4cm} 
\end{document}
```

The problem is, that it applies to all the pages in my latex-document and I only want it to apply to the first page with my pdf.

What can I do?

Comment: @Andrew `geometry` doesn't change the dimension of the physical page with `\newgeometry`.

Comment: If you need physically larger paper for document cover, than the only reasonable solution is to print it separately on larger paper size (see *egreg* comment) and add it to others manually. If you only need to change page layout for cower page but have the same physical paper size as have other sheets of papers in your document, then consider *Andrew* comment

Comment: I am new in the field, so I really will appreciate help. I only use share latex, so how should I find the manual?

Comment: @zahra, google can help you. for example: http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf.